# How to I make UDP and TCP flows simultaneously without multi-thread program

Tags: sockets

My program is like the following

sender side:

```
while(1){
   sendto(); // send some data packets
   usleep(); // delay to avoid overflow
}
```

receiver side:

```
while(1){
   recvfrom(); // receive
}
```

I could like to have a tcp socket appeared in receiver while loop, which send a control message (to change to time of usleep) from receiver side to sender side for every 2 seconds( or for every 100 received packets). In the mean while, the sender should also be able to listen this control message in while loop. Can it be achieved without a multi-thread program?

Comment: I guess you could set up a timer to poll your tcp socket with a certain interval.

Comment: Why not use the UDP socket by adding another UDP message that tells the receiver to change usleep?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I could like the control message to be reliable (i.e. TCP). BTW, how to write a "if condition" that it will be true for every 2 second after. Then I can reset the timer and loop again.

Comment: On Unix/Linux you could use `alarm()` and a signal handler, but getting that right is probably no easier than doing it in another thread.

Comment: Are non-blocking sockets (O_NONBLOCK) and select() available on your platform?